# How to Get Last Array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, cheerio

Using cheerio, I have managed to scrape a PHP generated table that contains a column of dates, locations, etc. As the number of rows is variable, I opted to use .map() to iterate through each row, setting the matching starting event dates (startDate) with the provided CSS selectors. The above process seems to be functioning well, as when I call console.log(startDate) I recieve the output below. it would appear, however, that the process creates an array for each time it moves to the next row, appending an additional date each time. How can I set a variable to only the last array in the array startDate?

```
[ '03/18/2014' ]
[ '03/18/2014', '03/01/2014' ]
[ '03/18/2014', '03/01/2014', '02/15/2014' ]
[ '03/18/2014', '03/01/2014', '02/15/2014', '01/31/2014' ]
[ '03/18/2014',
  '03/01/2014',
  '02/15/2014',
  '01/31/2014',
  '01/17/2014' ]
[ '03/18/2014',
  '03/01/2014',
  '02/15/2014',
  '01/31/2014',
  '01/17/2014',
  '12/06/2013' ]
[ '03/18/2014',
  '03/01/2014',
  '02/15/2014',
  '01/31/2014',
  '01/17/2014',
  '12/06/2013',
  '11/16/2013' ]
```

So the desired output of console.log(newArray) would be:

```
[ '03/18/2014',
  '03/01/2014',
  '02/15/2014',
  '01/31/2014',
  '01/17/2014',
  '12/06/2013',
  '11/16/2013' ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If startDate is an array, you should be able to get the last item in the array by using the index, like this:

```
var lastStartDate = startDate[startDate.length-1]; //now lastStartDate contains the last item in the array
```

Comment: Following up: It would appear that this results in the output '03/18/2014
03/01/2014
02/15/2014
01/31/2014
01/17/2014
12/06/2013
11/16/2013' Is there anyway I could have it output '[03/18/2014,
03/01/2014,
02/15/2014,
01/31/2014,
01/17/2014,
12/06/2013,
11/16/2013']'

Comment: Are you trying to output it into a string, joined with commas?

Comment: An array, with individual strings (the dates) seperated by commas. From what I can gather, using startDate[startDate.length-1] is outputting 7 strings, but that output isn't joined within an array. I want to be able to output an array, as described above, rather than simply outputting the elements within the last array.

Comment: If startDate is an array of arrays, then my answer I provided will get the last array within the startDate array. If startDate is something else, I would need to have a better understanding of what it is in order to provide a different answer. Why do you think it is outputting date strings separated with spaces? My answer will only do that if the last array within startDate is that.

Comment: I apologize, I failed to properly identify the types we were dealing with correctly. startDate is an array, which containes a series of dates, to which an additional date is appended each time untill all the dates have been appended to the array. I have discovered that cheerio is outputting these dates as objects. So we have an array (startDate) that is being iterated over appending each time a match is made on the selector, that -- on its last match/iteration -- contains a list of objects (dates). I want to only output the final array produced from all of the matched objects,